# How to change the header to a certain color?

Tags: header-footer, color, text

I am trying to make all the letters in my header red. I tried adding more hashtags, but that makes the text disappear if there are more hashtags than letters. If I make space for "Work Experience" the other headers go away. My code is attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're using `awesomecv`, right? Can you provide a link to a template?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
\patchcmd{\sectionstyle}% <cmd> ... within \sectionstyle,
  {text}% <search>              ... replace \color{text}
  {awesome}% <replace>          ... with \color{awesome}.
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

to your preamble (just before `\begin{document}`). The choice for `awesome` is because that's the default of the first three letters in every section.:

[image]